# How do I implement APIs in a search bar on VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, searchbar

I'm working on a university project and I'm stuck trying to implement a searchbar that takes Game names from an API (https://api.rawg.io/api/games) and, after clicking on a game, redirects the user to a page with the specific game URL. Now, I wish I was at least able to do the first part.

I have created a searchbar.vue component and copy-pasted the code from the official Vuetify library:
(https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/autocompletes/simple/api.vue)

However, if I change the API from the one they provide as an example to the one I need (rawg), it does not work anymore and I am not sure why.

**How can I make my searchbar work?**

I'm providing a link to codesandbox where I'm currently working, in case it's needed:
(https://codesandbox.io/s/searchbar-mtjr2?file=/src/components/searchbar.vue)

I will do my best to give more information about the issue if needed.

Thank you very much in advance for even considering this post.

Comment: [Here's a working version of searchbar.vue.](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchbar-forked-rdb4q?file=/src/components/searchbar.vue) The search bar works but for some reason I can't figure out, the search results are offset to the far right instead of staying under the search bar. If you cannot see the menu at all, view the [codepen in the browser](https://rdb4q.csb.app/), open the inspect menu (F12) and drag the page towards the left and you should see the search results like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/8f2a5f8655abd0ec157b1690cd9a60a1.jpg).

Comment: The only reason I can think of this happening is that you have some other styles that are interfering with the search bar, but I looked through the files and couldn't find any styles that could interfere with the search bar. You might want to ask a separate question if you can't find a solution to this on your own.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup First of all, thank you very much for your help. Your code does indeed work, which is great. However, now that I look at it, it only gives back the first 20 games (the first page of the RAWG API). My question is: I noticed there is an open API endpoint in the rawg API called "search" (https://api.rawg.io/docs/#tag/games). Do you think it would possible to use it in the searchbar somehow? Unfortunately I don't understand much about how to use endpoints properly.. as for the "graphical" bug, I will look into it! Thank you again for your help.

Comment: The search parameter would be good for searching games as long as the search is not performed at every keystroke. That would most likely just be slow then. What you can do if you want more results is append `?page_size=40` to the API URL so it looks like this `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=40`. You'd change `40` to the number of results you want to display, of course. Note that the request size becomes bigger as the number if games in the page increases, so data will load slower. 40 is not that much though, but if you set the size to 1000 or something, it may become slow.

Comment: If you want at add any parameters to the API URL, all you have to do is add a question mark after the url (`?`). Then add the parameters like `param=value`. Separate multiple parameters with ampersands (`&`). Something like this:`api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=40&search=Grand theft auto`

Comment: I just tested this url with `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=10000` 10000 results (not sure if it actually returned 10k though) and it loaded within about 2 seconds, so you should be fine loading a lot of results immediately. Also note that the example I gave doesn't 'lazy load' the results (lazy loading means only loading when necessary), instead it fetchs the results before the page is displayed, so that there is no lag between searching and receiving a response.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup I have tried setting up a page_size higher than 40 but apparently it does not load more than 40 items: could it be a limitation of CodeSandbox? 

What you said about the "as long as the search is not performed at every keystroke" makes total sense: if I look at https://rawg.io/, for example, I notice the website does not start searching for games until I stop typing. Something like that would be truly awesome. Oh, I wish programming wasn't so hard hahah.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm not getting it wrong, how do I check the size=10000 is correctly displayed? The dropdown menu of the search bar only shows the first 40 items and a quick search only shows those 40 items are the only ones found..

Comment: Yeah...well it gets easier. Anyways, if you can't get more than 40 results per page you could iterate through multiple pages and get more results that way. However searching when you stop typing is a good idea and I can write a demo for you with that later today perhaps (not sure what timezone you're in, but it's morning where I am) if you'd like.

Comment: I would love to, thank you very much for your help. I live in Italy (GMT +2), so it's 15:57 right now, but please, take your time! Your help is much appreciated. I could write you via email if you wish (I don't know how to get real-time notifications on this site) and then I could clean this request up and post the updates for future reference.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason the real time notifications don't work even on the mobile app. I don't ever get any notifications. Anyways if you'd prefer to contact me through email, my email is in my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all the problems with the search bar have been solved: [Demo here](https://rdb4q.csb.app/)

I added comments to the code so it should be clear how it works.

In **searchbar.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    clearable
    :loading="isLoading"
    :items="games"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    hide-details
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    label="Search for a Game..."
    solo-inverted
  ></v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    games: [], // this is where all the game data will be stored
    isLoading: true, // variable to determine if the results are still being fetched from the API
    search: null // this is where the query will be stored
  }),
  methods: {
    getGames(params = "") {
      // this function will fetch game data from https://api.rawg.io/api/games with whatever api parameters you pass to the parameter `params`
      this.axios
        .get("https://api.rawg.io/api/games" + params)
        .then(resp => {
          // fetch data
          let tempGames = [...this.games.slice(0), ...resp.data.results]; //copy of this.games + new data
          this.games = _.uniqBy(tempGames, "id"); // remove any duplicates
          this.isLoading = false; // now that the data is in the array `games`, we can set isLoading to false
        })
        .catch(e => {
          // code to run if there was an error
          console.error(e); // display error message
        });
    },
    searchGames(query) {
      // this function will call getGames() with the search query formatted as an API parameter (?search=YOUR_QUERY)
      let searchQuery = encodeURI("?search=" + query); // URI encode the query so it is able to be fetched properly
      this.getGames(searchQuery);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search: _.debounce(function(query) {
      // debounce with a a value of 250 will allow this function to be every 250 milliseconds at most. So if the user is typing continually, it won't run until the user stops.
      this.searchGames(query);
    }, 250)
  },
  created() {
    this.getGames(); // load the first 20 games initally
  }
};
</script>
```

This will:

1. Load the first 20 games
2. When you enter a query and stop typing, it will perform a request to `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?search=YOUR_QUERY`, and add the results to the `games` array. (So each time you search for something, the saved games array increases. That means that if you search for the same game twice, while it will still search online with `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?search=YOUR_QUERY`, the game will have been already in the games array from the first time, so it will be loaded immediately.)
3. `v-autocomplete` filters and displays the results.

This method will work better on faster connections, as the results are loaded faster. So if you have a slow connection, it may take time for the results to load. Unfortunately that's something that can't be worked around (although you could load a lot of data beforehand, but there's no guarantee that what you load is what the user will search for)

The graphical problem with the navbar was resolved by changing the parent `<div>` in App.vue to `<v-app>`, like so:

**Before:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

**After:**

```
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>
```

I also added [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) as a dependency for debouncing (waiting until the user stops typing) and removing duplicates.

Here's the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchbar-forked-rdb4q?file=/src/components/searchbar.vue) I was working on.

Do let me know if you have any further questions.